# I want to modify the network card name in ubuntu20.04 and add a virtual network card, What is wrong?

Tags: netplan

my goal:

1: Rename the network card “ens33” to “mangment_interface”.

2: Add a virtual network card named “provider_interface”.

How can I modify the code in the yaml file?

May be useful:

`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        mangment_interface:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
            addresses: []
        provider_interface:
            addresses: [192.168.95.130/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.95.1
            dhcp4: no
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
        enp0s8:
            dhcp4: true
            addresses: []
            optional: true
```

The display result of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:3b:28:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.95.130/24 brd 192.168.95.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 1789sec preferred_lft 1789sec
    inet6 fe80::63c0:b4a0:db9e:aca5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When executing `sudo netplan --debug apply`:

(Possibly useful part)

```
DEBUG:mangment_interface not found in {}
DEBUG:provider_interface not found in {'mangment_interface': {'dhcp4': True, 'optional': True, 'addresses': []}}
```

(All information)

```
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: starting new processing pass
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: enp0s8: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: mangment_interface: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: provider_interface: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: Generating output files..
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.381: networkd: definition mangment_interface is not for us (backend 2)
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.382: networkd: definition provider_interface is not for us (backend 2)
** (generate:4408): DEBUG: 21:02:13.382: networkd: definition enp0s8 is not for us (backend 2)
(generate:4408): GLib-DEBUG: 21:02:13.382: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
DEBUG:no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG:netplan generated NM configuration changed, restarting NM
DEBUG:mangment_interface not found in {}
DEBUG:provider_interface not found in {'mangment_interface': {'dhcp4': True, 'optional': True, 'addresses': []}}
DEBUG:enp0s8 not found in {'mangment_interface': {'dhcp4': True, 'optional': True, 'addresses': []}, 'provider_interface': {'addresses': ['192.168.95.130/24'], 'gateway4': '192.168.95.1', 'dhcp4': False, 'nameservers': {'addresses': ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']}}}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    mangment_interface:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    provider_interface:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.95.130/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.95.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: ens33
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for ens33
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the name used in netplan to identify an ethernet interface is expected to be the name presented by the kernel.

If you want to change the name of a device, you need to use a combination of `match` and `set-name`, as described in https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-physical-device-types.

E.g.:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    mangment_interface:
        match:
          name: ens33
        set-name: mangment_interface
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
```

It's a bit unclear what you mean by a "virtual network card".  If you mean a `veth` interface, there is currently no support for those in netplan as of version 0.100.  However, it is unclear to me why a veth interface (which is internal to the kernel, and attached to no physical links) would be something you would describe as a "provider_interface".  It's possible that what you are after is a vlan, but you don't mention vlan IDs anywhere in your question.

A vlan would look something like:

```
  vlans:
    provider_interface:
        link: mangment_interface
        addresses: [192.168.95.130/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.95.1
        dhcp4: no
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```